# Div with position fixed is offset by following element's margin-top

Tags: html, css

Why does `div.main`'s `margin-top: 50px;` move `div.fixed` down? Shouldn't an element with `position: fixed;` be fixed in the location it would have appeared with `position: static;` (at least when top/left are not specified)?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      /* optional: */
      .fixed {
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
      .main {
        height: 1000px;
        border: 1px solid green;
      }
      
      /* relevant: */
      .fixed {
        position: fixed;
      }
      .main {
        margin-top: 50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
    <div class="main">Inside main.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the example above, I'd expect "Fixed" to appear 50 pixels above "Inside main." but instead they are stacked on top of each other. My best clue so far is that adding something visible before `div.fixed` makes it work as expected. Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: can u plz add this code in codepen?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 here it is in codepen: https://codepen.io/rockysims/pen/gOpamgM?editors=1011

Comment: Do u want , do not merge with "Inside main" content right?